# How can I use aframe to create a 360 video effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, aframe

**CONTEXT**

We want to create an effect similar to what has been implemented [here](https://www.felixandpaul.com/?projects/jurassic). I am however looking to make the 360 video act as the hero element of a longer page.

**PROBLEM**

The best solution I've found so far for the 360 video is to use Mozilla's aframe, as is done [here](http://codepen.io/mozvr/pen/BjygdO). However, the problem I come against is that adding an `<a-scene></a-scene>` to my longer page essentially breaks the rest of the page, making me unable to see elements underneath (thought they are in DOM). One solution I found was to put the a-scene on a separate page and then display it in an iframe on my page. this works fine when I scroll next to the iframe, but scrolling does not work within the iframe.

Typical solutions for this scroll problem say to you use `overflow: hidden`, but this did not work so I thought maybe there is a different approach I can take, which makes mouse movements over the 360 video control the camera, whereas scroll controls the parent page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to embed an aframe scene into a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902305/how-to-embed-an-aframe-scene-into-a-div)

Answer (score 1):

https://aframe.io/docs/0.4.0/components/embedded.html

Use the embedded component then style the scene element.

`<a-scene embedded>`

Comment: This seems like the right solution, but for some reason adding embedded makes the inner image disappear from the screen - https://www.igotchamedia.com/arvr2/

Comment: you need to apply CSS

Comment: From what I can see, even applying height & width to the a-scene element as suggested elsewhere doesn't help here. Any particular CSS I should be applying to get the background image to show up?

Comment: Open the web console: `A-Frame:warn Put the A-Frame <script> tag in the <head> of the HTML before <a-scene> to ensure everything for A-Frame is properly registered before they are used in the <body>. +0ms`

Comment: It also works if I apply height and trigger a page resize